# What will be the value of i when it already initialize with 0 & with if condition & why?

Tags: c

This code gives a result of i = 1 but why it give this value when there is 5 and also initializing with 3.

```
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    if(i==0) {
        i=((5,(i=3)),i=1);
        printf("%d",i);
    } else{
        printf("Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you write code `i=((5,(i=3)),i=1);` like this and you do not understand it now (nor do I without a lot of thinking and guessing), what chance does another programmer in 6ths time trying to maintain this code has? Practically  zero

Answer (score 0):

The comma (`,`) operator returns the right side term. Here, the term that's returned is the return value of `i=1`, which is `1`. This value is then assigned back to `i`.

Comment: The behavior of the code is not defined due to C 2018 6.5 2: “If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined…” In this code, side effects of two assignments of a value to `i` are unsequenced.